# REST API - Method to avoid many requests to download images

Tags: rest, api

I'm sorry if the question is not understood correctly.

This is my case:

I have a back-end service with an API that returns a json object as usual. Also I have a mobile application that consumes that API, the response of one of the calls is a json that can contain several images url. my mobile application after getting the response from the API, download each image. These can be a lot of images to download, that is, many requests to the server for those images. What is the best thing to do, how can you manage these multiple downloads, is there a method, is there a technology, what is the best approach?

I guess it has been understood.
Regards!

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to limit access to your server and ensure good response for clients is to implement rate limiting. This way each client can only request so may resources in a set amount of time.

A common way to do this is to notify clients of their usage via the `X-Rate-Limit` family of headers and then provide a HTTP Status 429 `Too Many Requests` when that limit is exceeded. In the content of the `X-Rate-Limit` headers, the limit is exceeded when API calls are made with `X-Rate-Limit-Remaining` being `0`. This is from Twitter's API documentation:

> - `x-rate-limit-limit`: the rate limit ceiling for that given endpoint
> - `x-rate-limit-remaining`: the number of requests left for the 15 minute window
> - `x-rate-limit-reset`: the remaining window before the rate limit resets, in UTC epoch seconds
>
> When an application exceeds the rate limit for a given standard API endpoint, the API will return a HTTP 429 “Too Many Requests” response code, and the following error will be returned in the response body:
>
> `{ "errors": [ { "code": 88, "message": "Rate limit exceeded" } ] }`

Here's a link to the docs for Twitter and GitHub:

- GitHub: https://developer.github.com/v3/rate_limit/
- Twitter: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/rate-limiting.html